# grep with regex in middle of line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a log file entry that looks like this:

04/21 15:22:56 Information [jrpp-42] - Error Executing Database Query. Stored procedure 'dbo.get_discount' not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).  
The error occurred on line 67. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: /default.cfm || Location -- 10.8.79.7 || Browser --  || Querystring -- sshealth=1 ||  Referer --

I am trying to grep specifically for this part:

Error Executing Database Query. Stored procedure 'dbo.get_discount' not found.

However the part after dbo. is variable.  It's not always get_discount.  I'm trying to find the regex expression that will account for that and then still include the "' not found" string.

I can do this in two parts but I'm wondering if there is a regular expression that would work.  Thanks.

e.g  grep "Error Executing Database Query.  Stored procedure 'dbo.[REGEX]' not found."  filename.log

Answer (score 2):

```
grep "Stored procedure 'dbo.[^']*' not found" filename.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` or you can use `awk`. With `awk`  you have the advantage to do programming upon finding your string.

```
awk "/Stored procedure 'dbo.[^']*' not found/" file
```